# Size of HTML Box in Google site

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-sites

I am trying to insert a collapsible table with HTML Box in a Google site. The code of the collapsible table is from `http://tutorials.seowebpower.com/google-sites-advanced/collapsible-table`. The code is

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .container {
        background-color:deepskyblue;
        width: 600px;
        height:50px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .title {
        font-size: 16pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: aliceblue;
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;
        top:25%;
    }
    #opened {
        display: none;
    }
    .arrow-up {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 10px solid transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 10px solid white;
    }
    .arrow-down {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 10px solid transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent;
        border-top: 10px solid white;
    }
    .arrow-up, .arrow-down {
        position: absolute;
        top: 40%;
        right:15px;
    }
    .hidden-content {
        margin:0 0 20px 0;
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
        border: 1px solid deepskyblue;
        border-top: none;
        background-color: aliceblue;
    }
</style>
<script>
    var collapse;
    var uncollapse;
    var turnOn = true;

     // Chrome Sites Fix
    var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

    function tempChromefix() {
        // To turn off set true to false
        if (turnOn == false && is_chrome) {
            document.getElementById("opened").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("closed").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function uncollapse() {
        document.getElementById("closed").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("opened").style.display = "none";
    }

    function collapse() {
        document.getElementById("opened").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("closed").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="tempChromefix()">

<table id="closed">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="container" onclick="collapse()">
                <div class="title">Click to open drop-down</div>
                <div class="arrow-down"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="opened">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="container" onclick="uncollapse();">
                <div class="title">Click to close drop-down</div>
                <div class="arrow-up"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-content">
                <h3>It works!</h3>
                <p>This content is to be hidden from the user until clicked.   </p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I am facing is with width of the table. I would like it to have maximum possible width depending on the screen size. For example, I would like to have the table expand to the screen size in my MacBook as well as in iMac.

The logical way is to use the `width: 100%` so that the table inherits its parent's screen size. However it seems that inside an HTML Box the different categories does not inherit parent's attribute.

For example in the `.container` section, if I use `width: 100%`, it collapses to zero width instead of full size of the screen.

Would appreciate any help!

--- Madhur

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue also, and eventually figured out (the very un-intuitive) way is to hover over the HTML box, and then click on the "Align center" icon. When you save, elements will be the full width (my div's were at least).